# How can I show a DateTimePicker dialog box, when the user pushes a button (without having to add the control to the form)

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I am trying to make it so when the user pushes a button, a DateTimePicker dialog gets shown, and I would even like to get the resulting date they picked.  Here's what I have so far:

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim Dis As System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker = New System.Windows.Forms.DateTimePicker()

    ' Set the MinDate and MaxDate.
    Dis.MinDate = New DateTime(1985, 6, 20)
    Dis.MaxDate = DateTime.Today

    ' Set the CustomFormat string.
    Dis.CustomFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy - dddd"
    Dis.Format = Windows.Forms.DateTimePickerFormat.Custom

    ' Show the CheckBox and display the control as an up-down control.
    Dis.ShowCheckBox = True
    Dis.ShowUpDown = True

    Dis.Show()

End Sub
```

But when I push the button and run the code, nothing gets displayed.  I would think there ought to be a way to simply display this dialog programmatically.  Can anyone help me please? :-)

Just FYI, I'm coding this in VB 2010 if that helps any? :-\

Comment: You can't do this without a dialog (window) for it to display on. It's a control, not a dialog - it needs a parent window.

Comment: thank you for your response, in that case, is there some sort of "Popup" I can do to allow the user to choose a date from some sort of calendar dialog, or maybe is there some way to display it without assigning it to my form, because my form is actually a ribbon, and sadly the DateTimePicker's are not allowed :-(  That's my main problem, I need to allow the user to select a date from the ribbon. :-\ Sorry for the headache, that's why I was asking my question, because I'm having trouble finding some sort of workaround. :-\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I wound up doing, is I made a button, which opens up a separate form, which I made to look like a dialog, and put a `DateTimePicker` on.  That was the best workaround I could figure out how to do.

Comment: That's the correct approach -- a dialog is just a form with some in-built stuff.

Answer (score 6):

In vb.net, a `DateTimePicker` is not a dialog box like the `OpenFileDialog, SaveFileDialog, PrintDialog` or other similar dialogs.

Despite its 'popup' appearance the `DateTimePicker` is a control object, and as such it must be placed on (added to) a form or window before it can be displayed and used.

Comment: thank you for your response, in that case, is there some sort of "Popup" I can do to allow the user to choose a date from some sort of calendar dialog? :-\

Answer (score 0):

Add a form to your project and make it about the size of a calendar or date picker control.  I used a calendar:

```
Public Class frmDatePicker
    Private _Selected As Date
    Public Property Selected As Date
        Get
            Return _Selected
        End Get
        Set(value As Date)
            _Selected = value
        End Set
    End Property


Private Sub calPickDate_DateChanged(sender As Object, e As DateRangeEventArgs) Handles calPickDate.DateChanged
    Selected = calPickDate.SelectionStart

End Sub    
End Class
```

To use it:

```
Dim varDate As String = ""
Dim frm As frmDatePicker = New frmDatePicker()
frm.ShowDialog()
varDate = frm.Selected.ToString()

frm.Dispose()
'Do something with varDate
```